# Can we integrate PayPal payment API using email instead credentials?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

We have ecommerce website for multiple stores so seller can connect PayPal by themselves but sometimes they don't know how to get credentials/key, so is there any way to use PayPal email instead API key?

I am using API credentials, but I want to use PayPal email to make it simple.

Comment: this is not how encryption works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up a simple PayPal checkout for intent:capture payments, you can set a `payee` object when creating the order. See [pay another account](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/) for examples.

Other operations will require either the seller's Client ID and Secret, or permissions for a third-party integration.